# jQuery get the id/value of <li> element after click function

Tags: jquery, html, dhtml

How can I alert the id of the `<li>` item clicked?

```
<ul id='myid'>
  <li id='1'>First</li>
  <li id='2'>Second</li>
  <li id='3'>Third</li>
  <li id='4'>Fourth</li>
  <li id='5'>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

(Anything that can replace the id may be value or something else will also work.)

Comment: Try using event.target.id http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 148, accepted):

```
$("#myid li").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // id of clicked li by directly accessing DOMElement property
    alert($(this).attr('id')); // jQuery's .attr() method, same but more verbose
    alert($(this).html()); // gets innerHTML of clicked li
    alert($(this).text()); // gets text contents of clicked li
});
```

If you are talking about replacing the ID with something:

```
$("#myid li").click(function() {
    this.id = 'newId';

    // longer method using .attr()
    $(this).attr('id', 'newId');
});
```

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/q6yDe/) And to be fair, you should have first tried reading the documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/events/
- http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: how can you change this to work without jquery

Answer (score 14):

If you change your html code a bit - remove the ids

```
<ul id='myid'>  
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
<li>Fourth</li>
<li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Then the jquery code you want is...

```
$("#myid li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).prevAll().length+1);
});​
```

You don't need to place any ids, just keep on adding li items.

Take a look at [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAG9z/)

Useful links

- [jQuery prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

Comment: Thanks Shivik, but id is already defined. And I got the answer which I was looking for, in first answer. Thank again

Answer (score 1):

you can get the value of the respective li by using this method after click

HTML:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>show the value of li</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="pathnameofcss">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="user"></div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="pageno">
    <li value="1">1</li>
    <li value="2">2</li>
    <li value="3">3</li>
    <li value="4">4</li>
    <li value="5">5</li>
    <li value="6">6</li>
    <li value="7">7</li>
    <li value="8">8</li>
    <li value="9">9</li>
    <li value="10">10</li>

    </ul>

    <script src="pathnameofjs" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:-

```
$("li").click(function ()
{       
var a = $(this).attr("value");

$("#user").html(a);//here the clicked value is showing in the div name user
console.log(a);//here the clicked value is showing in the console
});
```

CSS:-

```
ul{
display: flex;
list-style-type:none;
padding: 20px;
}

li{
padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If You Have Multiple `li` elements inside an `li` element then this will definitely help you, and i have checked it and it works....

```
<script>
$("li").on('click', function() {
          alert(this.id);
          return false;
      });
</script>
```