# JQuery Selectors - get value of clicked id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a group of id elements:

```
<ul class='refine_checkbox'>
  <li id='check0' value='Large'><a href='#'>Large</a></li>
  <li id='check1' value='Medium'><a href='#'>Medium</a></li>
  <li id='check2' value='Medium'><a href='#'>Medium</a></li>
</ul>
```

My aim is for JQuery to return the value of the clicked id.
I can respond to the 'check' group of id's but I can't seem to return the value.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  $('[id^="check"]').each(function () {
      $(this).click(function () {
      alert("test")
      });
  });

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want the value or the id???

Comment: "My aim is for JQuery to return the value of the clicked id"

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery get the id/value of LI after click function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545341/jquery-get-the-id-value-of-li-after-click-function)

Answer (score 5):

Just one thing, attribute value is not valid for li (not in ol). and by the way in ol, value must be a number. I'm not aware it has changed for HTLM5.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  $('[id^="check"]').click(function () {
      alert(this.value)
  });

});
```

Comment: ya, because your code is not valid. If you use jquery 1.9.x or newer, you could use instead $(this).attr('value')  http://jsfiddle.net/kBJzw/  Or better, code with valid HTML. Here, you should use data-value=""  and then $(this).data('value')

Comment: Using data-value is the correct method I think.  At least I have a a working demo now.

Answer (score 2):

First you don't need `.each()`, just that is enough :

```
$('[id^="check"]').click(function(){})
```

Then to get the value, you do this :

```
$('[id^="check"]').click(function(){
    alert(this.value)
})
```

Comment: is using $(this).attr('value') better? ignoring the cast to a jquery object doesn't the attr function do some cross browser checks and normalizations?

Comment: If i am not misstaken, `.value` is compatible with every broswer. If I am right, `.value` will be better than `.attr()` since it reduce the number of calls, wich is important for optimisation. But again, if i am wrong and it is not compatible, then `.attr()` would be better for accessibility.

Comment: the .change event does not fire the alert box.

Comment: @LiviuT.  change nothing for attribute value as for inputs but it im quite sure you are right for textarea

Comment: My bad, i though it was checkboxs (because of the id). Stay with .click()

Comment: tbh I always use attr. IF there is ever a speed issue then I'll look into it then.

Comment: @LiviuT.  in the case of not valid attributes, you are right:  http://jsfiddle.net/SraUZ/

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
this.id
```

or

```
this.value
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `.each` just call `click` event
try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('[id^="check"]').click(function () {
      alert("test")
      alert($(this).attr('value'));  //alert(this.value);
   });

 });
```

Comment: This code just gives alerts just a "0" but not the value of the id clicked.