# Getting value from li created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the value from a dynamically LI I created.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545341/jquery-get-the-id-value-of-li-after-click-function?answertab=active#tab-top) which explains how to get it normally.

This is my code. This works perfect for the two elements I have on my LI.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="listPreReq" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto" role="menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
</ul>


$("#listPreReq li").click(function() {    
 alert($(this).html());  
});
```

But I have this option for adding more elements to the LI. All the new elements I added, they don't fire the $("#listPreReq li").click event. Not sure why. This is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/fohoca/3/).

```
$('#btPre').click(function(e) {
  var Psize= $("#listPreReq").find("li");
  Psize = Psize.size()+1;
  $("#listPreReq").append('<li><a href="#">Page '+Psize+'</a></li>');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Solution Demo](http://jsbin.com/zetehope/1)**

Instead of binding events to document you can even bind them to `ul`:

```
$("#listPreReq").on('click', 'li', function() {    
    alert($(this).html());  
});
```

Have a look at [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 4):

use `$(document).on('click','#btPre',function(e) {...` instead of `$('#btPre').click(function(e) {...` and it will be fired! it is called event delegation!

UPDATE: and also this part too:

```
$("#listPreReq li").click(function() {...
```

change it to:

```
$(document).on('click',"#listPreReq li",function() {...
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Still it doesn't fire. :http://jsbin.com/fohoca/4/edit $(document).on('click','#btPre',function(e) {