# Get Li Class Name on button Click

Tags: jquery

On Button Click i want to get the value of li.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="one">One Code</li>
  <li class="two">Two Code</li>
  <li class="three">Three Code</li>
</ul>

<button type="submit"  id="btnid" onclick="btnclick();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `li` don't have value... also which `li`?

Comment: Try searching before you post a question.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3545356/971502

Comment: Is this the only ul/li of your code, if it's not you could do it by selecting it, by descending from the ul, @emre in the above code there's no id  on the ul part, i think the link you pass didn't match his code!

Comment: i want li class name when click on any particular li @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
function btnclick() {
    var arr = [];
    $("ul.nav").find("li").each(function () {
        arr.push($(this).html()) //I don't know what you want, I am assuming the Html
    })
    alert(arr);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/1w9udsmf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

you can access each li like this with the jquery selector

```
$("a",CLASS_NAME,"li", "ul").text()
```

wich CLASS_NAME is .one .two .thre....