# How to get value in li using js in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<div id="radiodiv1">
         <ul id="span1" data-role="listview">
         <li>value1</li>
         <li>value2</label></li>
         </ul>
  </div>
  <br>
  <table style="border:none;">
  <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="item" />
 </td>
 <td>
    <input type="button" value="Add params to list" onclick="appendToList()"/>
    </td>
</tr>
        </table>
```

script

```
$(document).on("click", "#bizParams", function(e) {
    $("#span1").find("li").each(function(){
       var product = $(this);
       // rest of code.
       console.log(product);
});
});
```

when clicked the button am getting in log as

```
Object[li.ui-li-static.ui-body-inherit.ui-first-child]
Object[li.ui-li-static.ui-body-inherit.ui-last-child]
```

i have to get the values as value1 and value2

can someone say what was wrong here

Comment: where is `#bizParams` in your DOM structure???

Comment: there is a button but i forgot to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the `text()` property, not the entire object, change this:

```
console.log(product);
```

to this:

```
console.log(product.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`console.log(product.text());`

(it is plain vanilla jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

problem is with this line

```
var product = $(this);
```

You have to extract text

```
var product = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myid li").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // id of clicked li by directly accessing DOMElement property
    alert($(this).attr('id')); // jQuery's .attr() method, same but more verbose
    alert($(this).html()); // gets innerHTML of clicked li
    alert($(this).text()); // gets text contents of clicked li
});
```

[jquery get the id/value of LI after click function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545341/jquery-get-the-id-value-of-li-after-click-function)

Answer (score 0):

you should use :

```
        $(document).on("click", "#bizParams", function(e) {
    $("#span1").find("li").each(function(){
       var product = $(this);
       // rest of code.
       console.log(product.text());
});
});
```

bur before that add the `id="bizParams"` to your button.

```
 <input type="button" id="bizParams"value="Add params to list" />
```

Comment: besides adding a id `bizParams` to the button ... there is no need of using `.on()`(event delegation) here it should be used when we are adding html dynamically inside DOM ... you can use simple `.click()` here..@keerthanaalivelu

Comment: i did not change it because it was not doing any wrong.