# How to get the selected item value from auto-suggestion plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the jQuery mobile auto suggestion plugin. I  need to get the selected value from auto suggestion list  and use it into some other function.

Here is my code :

```html
<div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="customer">
    <li class="ui-screen-hidden" ><a href="1">BMW</a></li>
    <li class="ui-screen-hidden" ><a href="2">Mercedez</a></li>
    <li class="ui-screen-hidden" ><a href="3">Ciat</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
function getItem() {
  //Here i want to get the selected item from list 
  //Like value of option "BMW" is "1" I want to get that 1 value
}
```

Comment: This answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545341/jquery-get-the-id-value-of-li-after-click-function

Comment: spelling, wording, format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the clicked element by attaching and click handler and get the inner anchor href.

Code:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#mypage", function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#customer li", function (e) {
        alert($(this).text() +" - " + $(this).find('a').attr('href'))
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gkxgwx71/