# ajax how to get the specific value of clicked li?

Tags: jquery, get

I have created a dynamic list `<ul> <li> aa bb cc </li> </ul>`. as you can see [here](http://www.turkalpkucur.com/). from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545341/jquery-get-the-id-value-of-li-after-click-function)  link, I could get the whole clicked row. that is fantastic!  My question is , how could I get the name of the person? like, I want to alert just `murat` , not the whole thing.  `alert($(this).html().name)` not worked..

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: `.html()` returns a string, what do you expect `.name` to return from that?

Comment: You can use `String.prototype.split` to split a string into words separated by spaces. Or you can use a regular expression to parse a more complex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function LoadEmployees() {
    var ul = $("#employees");
    ul.empty();
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "../api/employee/employeelist"
    }).done(function (response) {
        //   console.log(response);

        if (response == null) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var emp = response[i];



            var li = $("  <li class='list-group-item'  id="+emp.id+">" + emp.id+" " + emp.Name + " " + emp.Surname +

                "(Cinsiyet:" + emp.Gender + " Maaş : " + emp.Salary + "$)</li>")
             .click(function () {
```

//I THİNK  I SOLVED MY PROBLEM. HOWEVER, NOW,  I AM TRYİNG TO SET THE COMBOBOX BASED ON CLİCKED İTEM. I UPDATED

```
                 $('#name').val(response[$(this).index()].Name);
                 $('#surname').val(response[$(this).index()].Surname);
                 $('#gender').val(response[$(this).index()].Gender);
                 $('#salary').val(response[$(this).index()].Salary);
         //     alert($(this).html()); // gets innerHTML of clicked li
           //   alert(this.id);



             });



            ul.append(li);
        }

    }).fail(function () {
        alert("Hata oluştu.")
    });
}
```